# Difference between `yield from foo()` and `for x in foo(): yield x`

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, yield-from

In Python most examples of yield from explain it with saying that

```
yield from foo()
```

is similar to

```
for x in foo(): yield x
```

On the other hand it doesn't seem to be exactly the same and there's some magic thrown in. I feel a bit uneasy about using a function that does magic that I don't understand. What do I have to know about the magic of `yield from` to avoid getting into a situation where the magic does something I don't expect? What advantages does the magic provide, that I should be aware of?

Comment: See [PEP-380](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033577/difference-between-generator-expression-and-generator-function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When `foo()` returns a regular iterable, the two are equivalent. The 'magic' comes into play when `foo()` is a *generator too*. At that moment, the `yield from foo()` and `for x in foo(): yield x` cases differ materially.

A generator can be *sent* data too, using the [`generator.send()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send). When you use the `for` loop, the `yield x` expression 'receives' the sent data; the `foo()` generator will never see this. But when you use `yield from` the sent data goes straight to whatever `yield` expression the delegated-to generator is currently paused at. In other words, `yield from` passes on the sent data so the delegated-to generator can receive it instead.

You can also raise exceptions *in* a generator, with [`generator.throw()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.throw); with the `for` loop case, the exception is raised from the `yield x` line, while with `yield from` the exception is passed on again; the exception is raised inside `foo()` instead.

Together, this means that `yield from` *in essence* replaces the current generator for the duration of the delegated iteration.

The delegated-to generator also gets to communicate with the parent generator, when done the `.value` attribute of the `StopIteration` exception raised is returned as the value of the `yield from` expression. You can set the value of that exception by using `return <expression>` in the delegated-to `foo()` generator, or you can use `raise StopIteration(<expression>)` explicitly.

`yield from` was introduced into the language with [PEP 380: *Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).

Comment: +1 for the simple explanation. `yield from` allows you to refactor a generator into several functions without changing the behavior of the code (though the nested generators are still not optimized as far as I know e.g., `O(n*k)` behavior is possible if you are implementing a power set instead of `O(n)` where `n=2**k`).

Comment: This really set the foundation of your answer: _"When `foo()` returns a regular iterable, the two are equivalent. The 'magic' comes into play when `foo()` is a generator too."_ Wanna delegate to another generator? Use `yield from`.