# python using yield from in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, yield-from

i have a list like:

```
list=['2,130.00','2,140.00','2,150.00','2,160.00']
```

i would like to use a function like

```
def f(iterable):
    yield from iterable
```

and applying

```
float(item.replace(',','')) for item in iterable
```

at the same time so that

```
f(list)
```

returns

```
[2130.00,2140.00,2150.00,2160.00]
```

I know

```
[float(x.replace(',','')) for x in list]
```

works here but it is to understand how to use yield from in a function
and modifying items in the iterable at the same time.
Maybe i have to use *args and/or **kwargs in the function but not sure i have and how to.

Comment: What isn't working here?

Answer (score 3):

`yield from` is a pass-through; you are delegating to the iterable. Either wrap the iterable in a generator expression to transform elements, or don't use `yield from` but an explicit loop:

```
def f(iterable):
    yield from (i.replace(',', '') for i in iterable)
```

or

```
def f(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield item.replace(',', '')
```

Comment: thanks so in the end yield from is not very useful in this type of context

Comment: @addequttorr: `yield from` is extremely useful when delegating to other generators. It is not the right tool for transforming the data from another iterable.

Comment: Are there any post documenting this?

Comment: @addequttorr: [Difference between \`yield from foo()\` and \`for x in foo(): yield x\`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25890604)